# How many nodes are in a perfect binary tree that is 32 nodes deep?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

According to a formula I found on Google it is 2^(32-1) = 2147483648, but that seems a little high. Is this correct?

Comment: why? 1st node = root node, which has 2 child nodes. now you have 3 nodes. each of those children has 2 child nodes themselves, so now you're up to 3+4=7. those 4 grandchilden have 2 nodes, so 7+8=15, etc...

Comment: ". . . but that seems a little high" reminds me of this quote: "the greatest shortcoming of the human race is our inability to understand the exponential function" -Albert Allen Bartlett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it isn't `2^(32-1)`.  It's `(2^32)-1`, or `4294967295`.

So...  even bigger than you had calculated.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove the actual result ((2^r) - 1 where r is the number of rows) using [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)!! Each row r in the tree contains 2^(r-1) nodes This is clear as each row contains double the number of elements of the last row, so the first row contains 2^(1 - 1) = 1 node, the second row contains twice this number 2^(2 - 1), 2 nodes.

Suppose that if we have r rows the formula for the total number of nodes is 2^r - 1. Check this for the trivial cases, 1 row has 2^1 - 1 = 1 nodes...

Now show that to go from the rth case to the rth + 1 row works So at the rth case we have (2^r) - 1 nodes to get the total number of rows for the (r + 1)th case we need to add on the (r + 1)th's nodes. The (r + 1)th row has  2^((r + 1) -1) nodes as discussed in the first paragraph. Adding this onto our current node total gives:

(2^r) - 1 + 2^(r + 1 - 1) = 2^r - 1 + 2^r = 2 * 2^r - 1 = 2^(r + 1) - 1

As this is the correct formula for the (r+1)th row we've proved the result.